# Continuous monitoring of data using BackgroundWorker (c#)

Tags: c#, controls, backgroundworker, motion

I need to monitor the position of a Rotary Encoder to control a DC Motor. To ensure that I wouldn't miss changes in the Rotary Encoder I have used BackgroundWorker.

My application hasn't worked as expected and so I'm debugging to see why it often misses the mark.

Using Console.WriteLine I'm writing out the state of the stopwatch and I've noticed that the thread is 'skipping' or missing loops, could this be a quirk of writing out to the console ?

Here's a small section of the output, as you can see there's a gap of 190ms :

```
Inside Thread. Time: 25, Position: 117, Velocity: 0
Inside Thread. Time: 26, Position: 117, Velocity: 0
Inside Thread. Time: 27, Position: 117, Velocity: 0
Inside Thread. Time: 28, Position: 117, Velocity: 0
Inside Thread. Time: 29, Position: 117, Velocity: 0
Inside Thread. Time: 30, Position: 117, Velocity: 0
Inside Thread. Time: 212, Position: 117, Velocity: 0
Inside Thread. Time: 213, Position: 117, Velocity: 0
Inside Thread. Time: 214, Position: 117, Velocity: 0
Inside Thread. Time: 215, Position: 117, Velocity: 0
Inside Thread. Time: 216, Position: 117, Velocity: 0
Inside Thread. Time: 217, Position: 117, Velocity: 0
```

Here's the code that I'm running inside the background worker (note it's currently just writing out to the console while I debug, when working it will control a DC motor) :

```
    public void dcMotorMove(DCMotorSettings dcMotorSettings)
    {
        try
        {
            dcMotorSettings.Moving = true;

            Stopwatch dcMotorStopwatch = Stopwatch.StartNew();
            dcMotorStopwatch.Restart();

            int MoveState = 1;

            while (MoveState != 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Inside Thread. Time: " + dcMotorStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds + ", Position: " + dcMotorControl.encoders[0].Position + ", Velocity: " + dcMotorControl.motors[0].Velocity);

                Thread.Sleep(dcMotorSettings.SampleRate); // Processor Rest
                if (dcMotorStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds > dcMotorSettings.Duration)  MoveState = 0;

            }

            dcMotorSettings.Moving = false;
        }
        catch
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Problem within dcMotorMove");
        }
    }
```

Comment: why do you think that some loops are missed? have you tried to introduce a counter, increment it with each loop and output its value to console? I see only that you can't establish precise execution of your code in terms of milliseconds which isn't surprising on a virtual platform like .NET and not realtime OS like Windows

Comment: Good point. Outputting a counter seems to be continuous. I was hoping that background worker would allow me to watch the encoder continually, however this seems to be not be the case. I'm going to have to change my approach.

Answer (score 2):

It's very highly unlikely to be a problem with `Console` class.

Only reason I can see that could cause this is that properties you are dumping to console (`Position`, `Velocity`) may take some time to evaluate, possibly due to limitations of connection you use.

See if you can live without 1000 samples per second and if your connection can support that. Or even if your library really refreshes so often or it sends you cached values from last read out.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that there is a bug here. There is no way to organize time precise execution of a code on a virtual platform (.NET) and not realtime OS. Stopwatch itself gives only the opportunity to measure time intervals. Your particular case depends on million of factors (like current processes running within the system, amount of memory etc)

Comment: I agree, I think I'm expecting too much to get 1ms response times. I'll turn down my sample rate and go from there.

Comment: Playing with various sample rates I've now found that anything below 10ms pauses causes erratic jumps. Everything above 10ms gives a predictable constant loop. Many thanks

Comment: Worth to say that the behavior may be different on another machine. With high probability

Comment: 150ms response time are not usual. If they were windows would be visibly slow for any interactive stuff. The .NET VM does not add significant pauses if you don't have a lot of GCs. This is not the cause.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a quirk of the console. Try printing dcMotorSettings.SampleRate as well.

Edit: Try changing the inner loop to:

```
            Console.WriteLine("Inside Thread. Time: " + dcMotorStopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds);
            Thread.Sleep(1);
```

If the effect still happens it is a operating system issue (or too much load on the system). If the effect doesn't happen you comment code in until it does again.

Comment: Samplerate prints out as the 1ms I expected it to be. Still with the 200ms ish jumps.

Comment: Added a new debugging technique.

Comment: Still the same behaviour. If I run the background worker for 2000ms then It's generally every 50ms that I get a gap of 200ms. I will attempt to switch off various events that are firing due to the hardware (Phidgets) I have attached .. perhaps even though they're handled in the main thread they're causing a bottleneck.

Comment: The ultimate test is to run the above code in a new empty console app. If the problem persists there must be some strange scheduling going on. Try on another PC next ;-)